# Simple dialog based application using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dialog

I want to develop a simple windows application (using C#) as follows:

- a simple dialog based application with three screens
- the first screen is just a screen to welcome the user and give some explanations on how to proceed
- the second one is a drop screen where the user can drop files on it (image files)
- it then performs operations on provided images and displays live results as a list view with status and percentage of completion

I already have the image manipulation code and this is the easy part to me, but I'm quite lost for the application itself...

Here are my questions:

- should I develop using winforms or WPF? I'd like to add my own font, have transparency on  images I use and display custom listview cells and controls...
- what is the best way of having multiple screens in a dialog based application? I was thinking of using a TabControl, hide the headers and programaticaly switch from the first screen to the second one once the user has clicked on a 'next' button, then to the third screen once files have been dropped on the window...
- and what would be the best way to have a background process that performs the operations on image files, giving user some feedback (progress bars with percents) without blocking the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I develop using winforms or wfp? I'd like to add my own font,
>   have transparency on images I use and display custom listview cells
>   and controls

I vote for WPF.

- it support more drag and drop operations
- it has better UI such as round corner and maybe transparancy (haven't used transparancy)
- very easy to custom listview and controls

> what is the best way of having multiple screens in a dialog based
>   application

For having multiple screen, you can use Frame, and change to different view using its source. It is also ok to use tab controls, but it provide user to skip page 2 and instead go directly to page 3.

> and what would be the best way to have a background process that
>   performs the operations on image files

BackgroundWorker will be useful for it. It should be thread safe.

Comment: Both support transparency, though its much easier in WPF.

Comment: Yes, I don't said that winform does not support transparancy

Comment: WPF is easier for working with layouts that need to Increase and Decrease in size

Answer (score 0):

here are my questions:
- should I develop using winforms or wfp? I'd like to add my own font, have transparency on

*It really depends. Do you know windows forms and/wpf? if you do both go with WPF
but if you don´t know either choose Windows Forms as it is easy.*

images I use and display custom listview cells and controls...
- what is the best way of having multiple screens in a dialog based application? I was thinking of using a TabControl, hide the headers and programaticaly switch from the first screen to the second one once the user has clicked on a 'next' button, then to the third screen once files have been dropped on the window...

*Once you get something working is easy for us to give you our opinion.*

and what would be the best way to have a background process that performs the operations on image files, giving user some feedback (progress bars with percents) without blocking the UI

*Both framerworks allow you to do just that. There is a great deal of options here, the easiest one, yet very usefull is the BackgroundWorked.*

thank you a lot for your time and for your help on these topics!!

Answer (score 0):

WPF is better on appearance, but I think WinForm is good enough in your case.

You might need to copy your font to Windows Font folder to use it.
However, it need authorize of the UAC.

I like `TabControl`, too. 
However, if you're going to restrict user that they have to follow your progress (cannot skip some tabs), you could use multi panels to instead of it.

If your background job is very simple, you can use the `BackgroundWorker` component.
Otherwise you need to create threads.